# can we use Multer with graphql to upload files?

Tags: api, graphql, multer

i was searching for some resources to implement file upload via graphql mongodb and Multer but i only see tutorials and things that are associated with rest-api's and multer so if you can help in this case please tell me your opinions

i was searching for some resources to implement file upload via graphql mongodb and Multer but i only see tutorials and things that are associated with rest-api's and multer so if you can help in this case please tell me your opinions

Answer (score 2):

`image.Resolver.js`:

```js
const { createWriteStream } = require("fs");
const { join } = require("path");
const { graphqlUploadExpress } = require("graphql-upload");

const storeUpload = async ({ stream, filename }) => {
  const uploadDir = "./uploads";
  const path = join(uploadDir, filename);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    stream
      .pipe(createWriteStream(path))
      .on("finish", () => resolve({ path }))
      .on("error", reject)
  );
};

const processUpload = async (upload) => {
  const { createReadStream, filename, mimetype } = await upload;
  const stream = createReadStream();
  const { path } = await storeUpload({ stream, filename });
  return { filename, mimetype, path };
};

module.exports = {
  upload: graphqlUploadExpress().single("file"),
  Mutation: {
    uploadFile: async (_, { file }) => {
      const result = await processUpload(file);
      const newFile = await File.create(result);
      return newFile;
    },
  },
};
```

`image.Schema.js`:

```js
module.exports = `
type File {
    id: ID!
    filename: String!
    mimetype: String!
    path: String!
  }
  scalar Upload 
   
  type Mutation {
    uploadFile(file: Upload!): File!
  }`;
```

`File.js`:

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = mongoose => {
  const newSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    filename: {
      type: String
    },
    mimetype: {
      type: String
    },
    path: {
      type: String
    }
  }, {
    timestamps: {
      createdAt: 'created_at',
      updatedAt: 'updated_at'
    }
  });
  const image = mongoose.model('image', newSchema);
  return image;
};
```